# ldap Authentication Error from java program

Tags: java, ldap

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{


    // Setup environment for authenticating

    Hashtable<String, String> environment = 
        new Hashtable<String, String>();

    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldap://192.168.0.100:389");

    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");

    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"uid=dilip.duraiswamy,dc=xxxx,dc=local");

    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"xxxx");

    try
    {
        DirContext authContext = 
            new InitialDirContext(environment);

        // user is authenticated
        System.out.println("USER IS AUTHETICATED");

    }
    catch (AuthenticationException ex)
    {

        // Authentication failed
        System.out.println("AUTH FAILED : "+ex );

    }
    catch (NamingException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Getting the error as 
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the authentication, add the correct distinguished name.

This issue is usually observed if the DN is not specified correctly in the case when it has space or some special characters.

​Here 52e – represents invalid credential

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21290631

Comment: thanks it worked for admin user , but not for normal user , can i know y its not working for normal user

Comment: for admin i used CN=username,CN=Users,DC=***,DC=local

Comment: for normal user im using CN=Dilip D,OU=IT,OU=***,OU=****,DC=****,DC=local its not working getting data 531 error i.e LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 531, v2580

Comment: Check whether the entered username is permitted to logon at this workstation